# Numeric values not displaying in Kafka consumer CLI

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Writing data from Avro file to topics by running Confluent 5.1.0.

when I ran Kafka consumer command, numeric values are not displaying.

```
kafka_2.12-2.1.0 root$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh
--bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic Initiate_scans
```

I can see the expected output in java logs.

Expected:

> {"app_id": "SQE", "app_name": "iSeal", "dev_stage": "DEV",
>   "scan_name": "Veracode", "seq_num": 1, "result_flg": "N",
>   "request_id": 5534, "scan_number": 1}
>
> {"app_id": "SQE", "app_name": "iSeal", "dev_stage": "DEV",
>   "scan_name": "Checkmarx", "seq_num": 3, "result_flg": "Y",
>   "request_id": 5534, "scan_number": 2}

Actual:

> SQE iSealDEVVeracodeN?V
>
> SQE iSealDEVCheckmarxY?V

Comment: maybe you need the avro console consumer, as the message is not serialized as string (default for console consumer)

Comment: got it..! thank you so much.
bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer.sh
--bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic Initiate_scans

above command gave me expected result.

Comment: glad to help mate : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kafka-console-consumer` will show UTF-8 decoded binary data.

If you have Avro in the topic that was producer by Confluent's `KafkaAvroSerializer` (or similar library), then you'll need to use `kafka-avro-console-consumer`, which will convert Avro into JSON records.